# 'The underlying connection was closed when using Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to get all links in my txt file to extract them using the Html Agility Pack but when extracting I get an error:

[image: Error Message]

Can you explain why?

Code:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("links");

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc = hw.Load(line.ToString());
           
    foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
    {
        string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);

        if (!hrefValue.ToString().StartsWith("http://") && !hrefValue.ToString().StartsWith("https://"))
            continue;

        if (!crawlListbox.Items.Contains(hrefValue))
        {
            crawlListbox.Items.Add(hrefValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes a connection is closed, this can be for many reasons, like internet connection problems, the problem with the server, or server may reject your request due to too many request in a short amount of time, etc, however you need to have error handing and may skip/retry the failed ones

Comment: What's the point of doing `line.ToString()` when `line` is a `string` already? This just makes it easier to make buggy code.

Comment: Please also show to the exception as text, not an image. Also the list of sites as text too and we could then try to replicate the error. We can't do that with an image.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I am requesting too many request in a short amount that's why. so do i need to use a thread so it can request more slowly or what should i use??

Comment: I have done many projects like this and I usually create a proxy provider class with hundreds of proxies and whenever the request gets rejected, the proxy provider sets a new working proxy. (My proxy provider checks proxies to make sure they work before setting them)